# ARIA for Multi-State Toggle Button?

Tags: button, wai-aria

I have a button that cycles through states on click: {off, red, blue, green}

Desired behavior would be:

1. When first focusing the button it announces something like: "My button, Green"
2. When clicking the button it announces only the state, like: "Red"

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It can be difficult to make a user interface that isn't "common" to be accessible.  For sighted users, is there a visual clue that the button has four states and that clicking on it, rather than performing an action, actually changes the state of the button?

This is often done with a "[segmented button](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/segmented-controls/)" that shows all the states possible and you click on the appropriate state you want.  Very similar to a radio group.  (The  URL links to Apple's Human Interface Guidelines but the same concept can be used for web.)

You can potentially use [`aria-roledescription`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-roledescription) to describe how your widget will function rather than having a basic "button" role announced.

To manage what is actually announced, you could have complete control of what is spoken by the screen reader by having an [`aria-live`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) region.  I've posted on live regions several times recently so I'll just [point to one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69765621/ios-voice-over-and-android-fail-to-announce-text-in-span-tag/69773586#69773586) (which in turn has links to a few other answers on live regions).